# "Packet for query is too large" in java web app with mysql

Tags: mysql, hibernate, tomcat, jpa, hikaricp

I have web application running on tomcat 7  on ubuntu and connecting to a mysql database on same machine. to manage the connection I'm using a Hikari data source and I use Hibernate as the ORM.

after running the server for few days I'm starting to get the following issue in the log files and all the requests starts to fail

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.PacketTooBigException: Packet for query is too large (1317 > 1024). You can change this value on the server by setting the max_allowed_packet' variable.
```

I have set the max allowed packet variable in the mysql server as below in [mysqld] section.

```
key_buffer              = 16M
max_allowed_packet      = 200M
thread_stack            = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
```

But I'm still getting this issue once few days and I need to restart tomcat and sometimes the mysql server too and once restarted it runs for another few days.

In client entity manager factory i have following

```
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.***" />

    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"
            p:databasePlatform="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"
            p:showSql="false" />
    </property>

    <property name="jpaDialect">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />
    </property>

    <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="javax.persistence.validation.factory" value-ref="validator" />
            <entry key="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="false" />
            <entry key="hibernate.format_sql" value="false" />
            <entry key="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="false" />
            <entry key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}" />
            <entry key="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="UTF-8" />
            <entry key="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer"
                value="true" />
            <entry key="hibernate.jdbc.use_scrollable_resultset" value="false" />
            <entry key="hibernate.jdbc.use_streams_for_binary" value="true" />
            <entry key="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size" value="10" />
            <entry key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="30" />
            <entry key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data" value="true" />
            <entry key="hibernate.default_batch_fetch_size" value="16" />
            <entry key="hibernate.order_inserts" value="true" />
            <entry key="hibernate.order_updates" value="true" />
            <entry key="hibernate.connection.max_allowed_packet" value="16905662" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I have followed few guides and configured the max_allowed_packet. but still getting the same issue. am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: I am also struggling with same issue. I am using Tomcat 8.0.30, MySql 5.5, Hibernate 5.1.0. I have found similar issues on https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=76816  and [another](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=76177) and [another also](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=80622)

Comment: As I posted in the previous comment, the outcome is, the value is again reset to 1M. Found the root cause, in the error.log where I found there are unresolvable ips which means your server is accessible from public. So someone has been hacking and execute some script without our knowledge. So better update the password from the default password and also block the default port from public access as well.

Now not facing any issues.

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered the same issues, but changing MySql configuration `max_allowed_packet=128M` and then restart MySql service as describe [here](https://blog.csdn.net/kinginblue/article/details/55522249)  solved the issue